# Can I save the Percy token to a file?

Tags: cypress, percy

I'm learning Percy and Cypress right now. I'm still working locally, without a CI. Since I have more than 1 project, I have to manually change the Percy token (using export PERCY_TOKEN=myToken in Terminal) every time I switch between projects. Can I avoid this by specifying the token in a file? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using macOS or Linux, if you have a [bashrc](https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-bashrc/) or [zshrc](https://linuxhint.com/configure-setup-zshrc-zsh/) file, you should be able to export the `PERCY_TOKEN` as a variable in that file.

```sh
export PERCY_TOKEN=myToken
```

After saving your `.*rc` file, you will need to either restart your terminal, or simply source the updated file.

```sh
source ~/path/to/.*rc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the export in the .zshrc. That's working. It's just that only 1 project is still possible. If I change the project and thus the token, I have to adapt the .zshrc again. Can't you save it in the project?

Comment: Are you using npm and a `package.json` file in your projects?

Comment: Yes, I am using those 2.

Comment: Awesome -- take a look at this for recommendations on using dotenv-cli and cross-var to manage variables from a .env file: https://medium.com/@arrayknight/how-to-use-env-variables-in-package-json-509b9b663867

Comment: Great, using `npm i dotenv-cli`, saving the token to a .env file, and then calling with `npm run percy:cypress` works as intended. The script section in package.json contains now `"percy:cypress": "dotenv -- percy exec -- cypress run"`.